# Como revierto la convercion fetch_array

Tags: php, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero mostrar el rut de todas las personas que tengan el nombre Pedrito por ejemplo, en una lista `ul` `li` de `html` pero pasa lo siguiente, que como transforme la variable `$row=pg_fetch_array` ya no me deja utilizarla para hacer una consulta en la DB, si alguien sabe como solucionar este problema, aunque me diga como puedo hacer lo que deseo, sería un gran favor.

```
<?php
        include 'conexion.php';
        $var_prueba=pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT *FROM prueba");
                while($row=pg_fetch_array($var_prueba)){
                    echo '<ul>'.$row['nombre'].'</ul>';

                    $aux="SELECT *FROM prueba WHERE nombre='$row'";
                    while($row2=pg_fetch_array($aux)){
                        echo '<ul>'.$row2['rut'].'</ul>';
                    }    
                }


 ?>
```

Comment: Y, ¿por qué no haces una sola consulta con el `WHERE` , por ejemplo: **`SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE nombre='Pedrito'`**?  ¿Por qué dos consultas?

Answer (score 3):

Es importante entender que `pg_query` devuelve un puntero o recurso hacia los datos, pero no son los datos en sí. Para obtenerlos tienen que aplicar uno de los métodos `fetch` para obtener los datos de ese recurso o puntero. Por eso siempre es un error intentar ejecutar consultas mientras lees resultados de una consulta previa, como intentas hacer aquí, porque el recurso de la consulta anterior sigue abierto.

En caso de necesitar esto, tendrías que terminar de leer los datos de la primera consulta, guardarlos en una variable y luego ejecutar la segunda consulta.

De todos modos, si lo que te interesa son los `rut` de las personas que se llamen `Pedrito`, puedes mandar a buscar sólo esos datos y luego leerlos.

Aquí vamos a traerlos agrupados, separados por coma y luego en una sola lectura los mostraremos.

El código sería este. He comentado entre líneas. Si hay algo que no entiendes lo puedes decir en comentarios:

```
<?php
    include 'conexion.php';
    #Filtramos directamente aquí y agrupamos por nombre
    $sql="SELECT nombre, array_to_string(array_agg(rut), ',')) as ruts 
            FROM prueba WHERE nombre='Pedrito' GROUP BY nombre";
    $var_prueba=pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
    $html="";
            while($row=pg_fetch_array($var_prueba)){
                $html.="<ul>$row[nombre]</ul>";
                #La columna ruts será un lista separada por comas con cada rut
                #Creamos un array con explode y mostramos cada rut en un li
                $ruts = explode(',', $row['ruts']);
                $html.="<ul>";
                foreach ($ruts as $rut){
                    $html.="<li>trim($rut)</li>";
                }
                $html.="</ul>";
            }
    echo $html;
?>
```